# What is the equivalent of the following tensorflow snippet in CNTK

Tags: python, cntk

I'm trying to implement [DDPG](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02971) in CNTK and came across the following code (using Tensorflow) to create the critic network:

```
state_input = tf.placeholder("float",[None,state_dim])
action_input = tf.placeholder("float",[None,action_dim])

W1 = self.variable([state_dim,layer1_size],state_dim)
b1 = self.variable([layer1_size],state_dim)
W2 = self.variable([layer1_size,layer2_size],layer1_size+action_dim)
W2_action = self.variable([action_dim,layer2_size],layer1_size+action_dim)
b2 = self.variable([layer2_size],layer1_size+action_dim)
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([layer2_size,1],-3e-3,3e-3))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1],-3e-3,3e-3))

layer1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(state_input,W1) + b1)
layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer1,W2) + tf.matmul(action_input,W2_action) + b2)
q_value_output = tf.identity(tf.matmul(layer2,W3) + b3)
```

where self.variable is defined as:

```
def variable(self,shape,f):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape,-1/math.sqrt(f),1/math.sqrt(f)))
```

Ignoring the random initialization (I just want the structure) , I tried the following:

```
state_in = cntk.input(state_dim, dtype=np.float32)
action_in = cntk.input_variable(action_dim, dtype=np.float32)

W1 = cntk.parameter(shape=(state_dim, layer1_size))
b1 = cntk.parameter(shape=(layer1_size))
W2 = cntk.parameter(shape=(layer1_size, layer2_size))
W2a = cntk.parameter(shape=(action_dim, layer2_size))
b2 = cntk.parameter(shape=(layer2_size))
W3 = cntk.parameter(shape=(layer2_size, 1))
b3 = cntk.parameter(shape=(1))

l1 = cntk.relu(cntk.times(state_in, W1) + b1)
l2 = cntk.relu(cntk.times(l1, W2) + cntk.times(action_in, W2a) + b2)
Q = cntk.times(l2, W3) + b3
```

But, the initialization of layer2 failed with the following error (snippet):

> RuntimeError: Operation 'Plus': Operand 'Output('Times24_Output_0',
>   [#, *], [300])' has dynamic axes, that do not match the dynamic axes
>   '[#]' of the other operands.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and how to accurately recreate the same model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you have define `state_in` as `cntk.input` and `action_in` as `cntk.input_variable` which by default have slightly different types: `cntk.input` by default creates a variable that cannot be bound to sequence data, while `cntk.input_variable` by default creates a variable that must be bound to sequence data (N.B. `input_variable` is deprecated and some IDEs like PyCharm will show this with a strikethrough, please use cntk.input() or cntk.sequence.input()).

The error says that the plus operation cannot add `cntk.times(l1, W2)` which has dynamic axes [#] (meaning the minibatch dimension) with `cntk.times(action_in, W2a)` which has dynamic axes [#, *] (meaning the minibatch and sequence dimension).

The simplest fix is to declare

`action_in = cntk.input(action_dim, dtype=np.float32)`

which makes the rest of the operations typecheck.

Comment: Thanks! My frustration must have clouded my vision.